# How to upload multiple images at once

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I want to upload many images at once.
I found a lot of questions and articles about this subject, but I still do not understand.

**HTML**

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart(base_url() . 'admin/news/addNews_processing') ?>
<input type="file" name="image_upload[]" />
<input type="file" name="image_upload[]" />
<input type="file" name="image_upload[]" />
<input type="file" name="image_upload[]" />
<input type="file" name="image_upload[]" />
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

**PHP**

```
$config['upload_path'] = FCPATH . "assets\uploads";
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
$config['max_size'] = '1024';
$this->load->library('upload');
foreach ($_FILES['image_upload']['name'] as $key => $value) {
    if (!empty($value))
        $this->upload->do_upload($value);
}
```

**What is the error in the above code ?**

Comment: duplicate question see here for your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377218/upload-multiple-files-in-codeigniter

Comment: @TonyCarter: I have seen this question before, but does not work with me.

Comment: Please refer this stack.I've resolved this in there.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377218/upload-multiple-files-in-codeigniter/38335984#38335984

Answer (score 0):

In your foreach loop you are checking to see if `$values` is not empty, but in the foreach definition you use `$value` which I don't see defined anywhere.

```
if (!empty($values))
```

should probably be

```
if (!empty($value))
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the reason of problem. I made the mistake when I was writing the code

Answer (score -1):

Your input name should be different. Because, when you will call it, it will get multiple conflicting results

HTML

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart(base_url() . 'admin/news/addNews_processing') ?>
<input type="file" name="image_upload1" />
<input type="file" name="image_upload2" />
<input type="file" name="image_upload3" />
<input type="file" name="image_upload4" />
<input type="file" name="image_upload5" />
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

PHP

```
$config['upload_path'] = FCPATH . "assets\uploads";
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
$config['max_size'] = '1024';
$this->load->library('upload');
for($i=1;$i<=count($_FILES); $i++)
{
$this->upload->do_upload($_FILES['image_upload' . $i]['name']);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but still does not want to upload the files, also the number of fields is not fixed.

Comment: numbers is fixed, see the code, and what error is coming when upload failed? see using, $_FILES["file"]["error"]

Comment: `Message: is_uploaded_file() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`, also there is another message `You did not select a file to upload.` I have selected files.

Comment: print_r ($_FILES['image_upload' . $i]['name']) inside for loop , will give you structure of $_FILES['image_upload' . $i]['name'] if it is array , convert it to string then use of you can give it to me.

Comment: Note: I'm still using `<input type="file" name="image_upload[]" />`, I can't use this `<input type="file" name="image_upload1" />`, `image_upload1`, `image_upload2` etc. because the fields number are dynamic, I have used javascript to add more new fields

Comment: check your codes again this will be something like image_upload[1],image_upload[2],image_upload[3].... like this, name of all input cannot be same.

Comment: I have done what you said, and I have changed the names of fields as you said, and there are no errors except this message `You did not select a file to upload.`

Comment: when you will load the page at first time you will get this notice. whatever, then you have to select all files that you want to upload and then submit it.

Comment: The problem was solved, this line must be like this `$this->upload->do_upload('image_upload' . $i)`