# Multiple file upload in usnig codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here is my input filed

```
<input type="file" name="image1">
<input type="file" name="image2">
```

Here is my single file upload controller function.If i want to upload multiple file then what to do.

```
  function upload(){
           $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
                $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
                $this->load->view('error', $data);
                } else {                         
                    $file_data =  $this->upload->data();                        
                    $request_profile =array();
                    $request_profile['request_id']= $request_id;
                    $request_profile['profile_photo_location'] = $file_data['file_name'];
                    $request_profile['full_pp_name']=$this->input->post('full_pp_name');
                    $this->test_model->insertTableData('request_profile',$request_profile);

                   }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default you can't upload multiple files in Codeigniter. But you can use this to achieve that.

https://github.com/stvnthomas/CodeIgniter-Multi-Upload

For info on how to upload more than one file, not an array, look at this.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8381575/4099592