# Codeigniter multiple file upload with input array key

Tags: file, codeigniter, upload

I have two input field as below;

```
<input type="file" name="datainfo[site_logo]" class="custom-file-input" id="site_logo">
<input type="file" name="datainfo[site_fav]" class="custom-file-input" id="site_fav">
```

How can i upload two files with foreach ? I have tried a few methods but i couldnt achieve this.

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload multiple files in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377218/upload-multiple-files-in-codeigniter)

Comment: My paramters are different from this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok if you insist to keep it like that with your parameters and input names, then you have to restructure `$_FILES` array before `do_upload()`:

```
public function upload()
{
    $count = count($_FILES['datainfo']['name']);
    for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++)
    {
        foreach ($_FILES['datainfo'] as $key1 => $value1)
        {
            foreach ($value1 as $key2 => $value2)
            {
                $files[$key2][$key1] = $value2;
            }
        }
    }
    $_FILES = $files;
    $config['upload_path'] = FCPATH.'uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '2048';
    $config['max_width'] = '1920';
    $config['max_height'] = '1280';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    foreach ($_FILES as $fieldname => $fileObject)
    {
        if (!empty($fileObject['name']))
        {
            $this->upload->initialize($config);
            if (!$this->upload->do_upload($fieldname))
            {
                $errors = $this->upload->display_errors();
            }
            else
            {
                 $success = 'Success';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tested it in my environment with your inputs as it is and it works fine.

Comment: You're welcome bro, glad it works .. you can select it as correct answer.