# How to upload 2 file input in one form Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem with how to upload 2 file input in 1 form CI 3 with different file name. My view code: There is have 2 file input, 1. file_sertifikat and 2. file_rekomendasi

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="file_sertifikat">File Sertifikat</label>
<input type="file" name="file_sertifikat" class="form-control" id="file_sertifikat">
<small class="text-danger"><?= form_error('file_sertifikat') ?></small>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="file_rekomendasi">File Rekomendasi</label>
<input type="file" name="file_rekomendasi" class="form-control" id="file_rekomendasi">
<small class="text-danger"><?= form_error('file_rekomendasi') ?></small>
</div>
```

My Controller action to save filename to database:

```
$file_sertifikat = $this->upload_file_sertifikat($this->input->post('file_sertifikat'));
    $file_rekomendasi = $this->upload_file_rekomendasi($this->input->post('file_rekomendasi'));

    $data = array(
      'file_sertifikat' => $file_sertifikat,
      'file_rekomendasi' => $file_rekomendasi,
    );

    $this->perizinan_model->insert_data($data,'perizinan');
    redirect('admin/perizinan');
    }
```

and my upload file function:

```
        public function upload_file_sertifikat(){
            $config['upload_path'] = './assets/uploads';
            $config['file_name'] = 'file_sertifikat_'.rand(1, 99999);
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf';
            $config['remove_space'] = TRUE;
            $config['max_size'] = 10048;

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if($this->upload->do_upload('file_sertifikat')){
                    return $this->upload->data("file_name");  
            }else{
                    return "defaultimg.png";
            }
        }

        public function upload_file_rekomendasi(){
            $config['upload_path'] = './assets/uploads';
            $config['file_name'] = 'file_rekomendasi_'.rand(1, 99999);
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf';
            $config['remove_space'] = TRUE;
            $config['max_size'] = 10048;

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if($this->upload->do_upload('file_rekomendasi')){
                    return $this->upload->data("file_name");  
            }else{
                    return "defaultimg.png";
            }
        }
```

I want to upload that 2 different filename one by one, but my code overwrite the file. Thank before.

Comment: try this [upload multiple files ci3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53826617/5609501)

Comment: @SherifSalah i have see that, but at there is with array, while i want to upload the file different field

Answer (score 0):

In html change

```
<input type="file" name="file_rekomendasi" class="form-control" id="file_rekomendasi">
```

to

```
<input type="file" name="file_rekomendasi[]" class="form-control" id="file_rekomendasi" multiple >
```

In the controller, you will get $file_rekomendasi as an array. Handel that as like array. Run a loop.

Comment: But there is have 2 different field, file_rekomendasi and file_sertifikat

Comment: for multiple insert arrays, you have to generate the array from the input field array. Just run loop inside loop.