# is_uploaded_file() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given while upload multiple files in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, multifile-uploader

i am unable to upload multiple

Here is my view form

```
<form method="POST" action="<?=base_url()?>register/saverecord" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file_upload[]"  multiple="multiple" value=""><br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT">
    </form>
```

here is my code for multiple upload

```
public function saveRecord() {
        $config['upload_path'] = APPPATH . './uploads/';
        $path = $config['upload_path'];
        $config['allowed_types'] = '*';
        $config['max_size'] = '1024';
        $config['max_width'] = '1920';
        $config['max_height'] = '1280';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $fileName = [];
        foreach ($_FILES as $fieldname => $fileObject) //fieldname is the form field name
        {
            if (!empty($fileObject['name'])) {
                $this->upload->initialize($config);
                if (!$this->upload->do_upload($fieldname)) {
                    $errors = $this->upload->display_errors();

                } else {
                    $fileName[] = $this->upload->data();
                }
            }
        }
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($fileName);
        echo "</pre>";
        exit;
    }
```

Here is my error message i am getting after upload[image]

I followed this url [Upload multiple files in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377218/upload-multiple-files-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!$this->upload->do_upload($fieldname)) {
```

Here `fieldname` is an array, you need to have individual files here instead of array.

Answer (score 0):

Try Out This code, It will work. You are passing array to do_upload function. That is not valid. I corrected the code please check after replace this code.

```
public function saveRecord() {
        $config['upload_path'] = APPPATH . './uploads/';
        $path = $config['upload_path'];
        $config['allowed_types'] = '*';
        $config['max_size'] = '1024';
        $config['max_width'] = '1920';
        $config['max_height'] = '1280';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $fileName = [];
        foreach ($_FILES as $fieldname => $fileObject) //fieldname is the form field name
        {
            if (!empty($fileObject['name'])) {
                $this->upload->initialize($config);
                if (!$this->upload->do_upload($fileObject['name'])) {
                    $errors = $this->upload->display_errors();

                } else {
                    $fileName[] = $this->upload->data();
                }
            }
        }
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($fileName);
        echo "</pre>";
        exit;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When processing a `multiple file` upload you can access the various files like this - how you tie that in with the native methods available to you via `codeigniter` I don't know

```
foreach( $_FILES[ 'fieldname' ] as $i => $void ){
    $name=$_FILES[ 'fieldname' ]['name'][$i];
    $tmp=$_FILES[ 'fieldname' ]['tmp_name'][$i];
    $size=$_FILES[ 'fieldname' ]['size'][$i];
    $type=$_FILES[ 'fieldname' ]['type'][$i];

    /* other code */

}
```